# Are exosolar trajectories of spacecrafts and their gravitational behaviour in Milky Way off-topic on Space Exploration SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked these two questions [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40460/33950), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41189/33950) that are related to spacecraft trajectories outside the Solar system.
The primary reason why I asked them was to assist in my understanding and visualization (with regards to the galaxy plane) of the current and future trajectories of the [5 spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artificial_objects_leaving_the_Solar_System) that are leaving the Solar System (maybe I should've asked that question directly to start with).

It was [suggested](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41189/what-will-happen-to-a-spacecraft-if-it-cancels-its-galactic-velocity#comment134085_41189) for one of the asked questions that it was

> ...probably more likely to receive authoritative answers in Astronomy SE than (it) might here, and galactic trajectories might not even be on-topic here since they don't reflect aspects of Space Exploration normally discussed here. But let's see what happens!

Below are the current related guidelines on [what topics to ask](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Trajectory design, orbital and celestial mechanics

and what topics not to ask:

> Physical sciences, such as geology, astronomy, cosmology, meteorology, except as they relate to spacecraft and space exploration

So I decided to bring this up here. 
I would kindly ask members of the Space Exploration community to express their opinion here (to obtain some kind of "voting"): if there would be 5 opinions expressed, and 3 of them would be that the asked questions don't really belong here, I would intend to delete them here and reask on Astronomy SE (unless there is a procedure to transfer existing question between the sites).

Comment: If it were my question, I'd ask it on the site where it's likely to get the best answer. A few years ago I used reflexively challenge topicality recommendations. but then I realized that I was being guided towards the best answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are on topic here. Of course, as uhoh said, you may decide that other sites will get you better/quicker answers to these types of questions, but they are perfectly welcome here.

That said, I'm pretty sure both of these are actually *off topic* on Astronomy. We have ruled that questions about spacecraft are only allowed when they are about doing astronomy with a spacecraft, or questions about observing satellites' orbits. In this case, I think the suggestion to move the question there was bad advice.

Comment: You're right of course. Thought the spacecraft aspect is [in my opinion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41189/what-will-happen-to-a-spacecraft-if-it-cancels-its-galactic-velocity#comment134167_41189) a red herring, as currently written it shouldn't be moved there, even though (also in my opinion) the people who can write the most authoritative answer are there.